# virtualmin - change of pdo_mysql.default_socket for CGI and FCGId

Tags: mysql, php5

I am runing virtualmin with mysql and php on ubuntu 10

recently I have update mysql and php to newest version since than My pdo_mysql.default_socket has changed from `/tmp/mysql.sock` to  `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. I have done the php.ini file update. and it is working fine in `Apache mod_php mode.`

but it is not working in `cgi and fcgid mode`. 
What/where I can do the change so that other modes will also start picking up new socket.

```
1. Apache mod_php (run as Apache's user)
2. CGI wrapper (run as virtual server owner)
4. FCGId (run as virtual server owner)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most probably different `php.ini` files for the different modes. I suggest you create new PHP script which invokes `phpinfo();` and call that script in your browser. The resulting HTML page will show you among other things where PHP expects the `php.ini` file.

Comment: I already did that, and findout all the php.ini files and changed them. but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Wayaround, which I find is create a link using command  in your directory /tmp/mysql.sock
`ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`

I still could not find out why FCGId in virtualmin not picking up changes in php.ini file. I have provided the above way arround for anyone who reach on this thread having same issue.

Comment: This solution worked for me.